# One-to-one relationship with two models (fields) in Django to the current model

Tags: python, django

How to have one-to-one relationship with two models (fields) in Django (User and Product to be one-to-one together to Review)? So one user should have one review per product. Is there a built-in solution in Django models? Obviously having them both foreignkeys would be wrong as given here.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Review(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user    = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You could add a unique_together-constraint, e.g. `unique_together = ['user', 'product']` ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments: Use a `unique_together`-constraint. [[Django Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

You set it in the `Meta`-class of a model:

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user    = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'product']
```

Comment: I ended up using `UniqueConstraint` which seems to be the recommended way by Django whereas `unique_together` may be deprecated in future versions. But both are correct as of current version.